# ASP.net MVC configuration issue without mod_mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mono, apache2, mod-fcgid

We're developping an MVC .Net website supposed to run on linux.
It worked fine with mod_mono but we're forbidden to actually use mod_mono on the production server for performance matters. Also, we use mono-fastcgi-server2 and mod_fcgid.

So when disabling mod_mono, the home page still works fine but any request like /controller/action ends up with a 404 error.

I wonder if we can even run our MVC .Net website without the mod_mono ?

This is my first question on this website and I am not very familiar with apache and the modules. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

mod-mono is the Mono project's ASP.NET module for Apache.  Without it, there's nothing in Apache to interpret any ASP.NET content.  So, by extension, if you're not allowed to run mod-mono on your Apache server then you're not allowed to run ASP.NET on your Apache server.

Comment: Thanks, but the home page works, and it has ASP.Net code in it, doesn't that mean we actually can run ASP.net code ?

Comment: @user2474965: What's the code that actually works?  What is the server-side code and what renders client-side?

Comment: So far our project is just initialized from a visual studio template. The home page displays two tabs, "Home" and "About", and a message like "Welcome on MVC.Net" that is set by the controller to the view. 
I feel like the problem lies in dealing with the urls like /controller/action, like a rewriting or rerouting issue, but have no idea where to start. For instance, the "About" button doesn't work for it is an action of the Home controller.

Comment: @user2474965: I suspect that this is coincidentally serving some static HTML from the default of the site.  Though it's hard to be certain without seeing anything.  If the server-side code genuinely says something like `@Html.ActionLink()` and that's becoming an actual `a` tag on the client side, then you're right that *something* is interpreting the ASP.NET content.  I'd be very curious as to what that something is.

Comment: Then I have to make sure whether it is some static HTML as you suggest or .Net code actually being ran. I guess if i'm writing some c# code with string and it operations and displaying the result, that means the c# code is actually being interpreted.